# ES6 Modules, VueJS And TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings, es6-modules

I am trying to create a minimalistic setup and want to use the above features.. So in my JavaScript code I have a:

```
<script type="module" src="./myapp.js"></script>
```

which loads the myapp.js module. Inside the myapp.js I want to create a Vue component. Ofcourse I want to write this component with TypeScript (myapp.ts) and transpile this to js. However, to get typeinfo inside the .ts code I have to import Vue typings like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
```

When I transpile this, this code is maintained in es2015 module syntax (because of my tsconfig.settings), the result is this javascript:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
```

and the browser does not accept this named import.

The question is: (how) can I import typings that are exported without importing it using the above statement. I tried ///  syntax but the types still were not available. Is this because the types are explicitly exported and therefore need to be imported using the import syntax?

Is there a way to get the typings without import? Is there a way to use the named import to get the typings but exclude that line for transpilation? Is there another way to achive this (without the webpack or other setups)?

Thanx 
John.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a minimal Vue app by just loading `vue.min.js` with a script tag. Then you don't need to `import Vue`.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Then you can load your modules using

```
<script type="module" src="mymodule.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
```

By the way, this is not about typings, but about importing the actual Vue code that allows you to create Vue components. You don't need to import typings at all.

Comment: Correct. But I want to use typescript to get stronger type checking and intellisense etc. So I want to write typescript code that transpiles into an es6 module that can be loaded in chrome.

Comment: Type checking should happen automatically if you have the type definitions file in your project directory (no need for import). The file is included when you `npm install Vue` or you can get just the `vue.d.ts` file from `npm install @types/vue`

Comment: Actually: npm install @types/vue says that Vue comes with its own types, but these are module based and therefore forces me to use the import Vue from 'vue' to get its type info.. I want to have this type info globally, thus without the import statement so this does not get transpiled to the resulting .js file.

Comment: I see your point, the `.d.ts` file itself uses export. I did not realise that :) I made a test where I just removed the export statements from `vue.d.ts`. so `export interface Vue` becomes `interface Vue`. That gives you type checking in the IDE....

Comment: Yea thanks, so removing the exports and imports from the package makes it a global type definition... but then I have to resolve the imports and remove the exports all the way to the end of the dependency tree... :-( Thanks for the comfirmation :-)

Comment: Yeah but perhaps a quick find and replace `export` with `` is enough? You only need to traverse the `.d.ts` files. (5 files I believe)